# Page show up in the Apps Panel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sidebar

I a have a facebook app, however it does not show up in the Apps listing at all (of users who have already approved the permissions).  How do I make my App show up as an "App" so users can add it to there sidebar?  Is there a way to prompt users to make my App one of their favorites?

**First question**: Why is my App not showing up at all as an App?
**Second Question**: How can I get my App placed on a user's side bar, in the "Apps" panel list?

http://www.facebook.com/familypot.poker?sk=app_195976757147974

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Since July 2010 bookmarks are added automatically for apps a user has interacted with there is no facility to manually add bookmarks ([look here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/bookmark/) and also
[look here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) under **Bookmarks for quick re-engagement**)
**Second**: I remember that I managed once to have the bookmark automatically added using an authentication process like desribed [in the update of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6940261/601466). However I'm not sure whether this will work for your app.